# What is the proper way of cloning child component's template in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am stuck with a concept about cloning a component's template.

So I have a `RequestComponent` (parent component) that has a method (bound to a button click) to load the `DestinationComponent`'s template (child component).
The method can be called multiple times for a single Request meaning that there could be several destinations.

```
addDestination(){
    let nextDestinationArr = {
      'nextDestinationLat': '',
      'nextDestinationLng': '',
      'nextDestinationAddress': '',
      'nextDestinationFullname': '',
      'nextDestinationMobile': '',
      'nextDestinationDescription': ''
    };
    this.nextDestinations.push(nextDestinationArr);    
  }
```

The Destination template has a form that accepts the Destination details, and it works fine for the first destination But since there may be more than one destination, the problem raises.

```
export class DestinationsComponent {

  nextDestinationLat: string;
  nextDestinationLng: string;
  nextDestinationAddress: string;
  nextDestinationFullname: string;
  nextDestinationMobile: string;
  nextDestinationDescription: string;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

and then in request template:

```
<div *ngFor="let nextDestination of nextDestinations">
  <destinations></destinations>
</div>
```

Filling the new destination form updates the previous attributes which is thoroughly logical. Sounds like I need to clone the component in a way that the new component and it's template has new (suffixed incrementally) set of attributes to get matched. Something like:

```
nextDestinationLat2: string;
nextDestinationLng2: string;
nextDestinationAddress2: string;
nextDestinationFullname2: string;
nextDestinationMobile2: string;
nextDestinationDescription2: string;
```

I need help with the concept and have no idea how to solve this. please help me with a proper approach.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the problem, but you should clone the object instead:

```
 this.nextDestinations.push(Object.assign({}, nextDestinationArr));
```